# Link encoded in QR code - is there a way to encode so that the result will be the same regardless to the OS current language?

Tags: java, barcode, barcode-scanner

I encoded a link in a QR code and the problem is that the link has the caracter ":" and the phisical key from the keyboard that has ":" is not the same in all languages.

So if I change the language from the windows OS the scanned code will be different.

I have no control over the apps that will scan the code, is there a way to encode the link in such a way that it will be scanned the same regardless of the OS language?

I use Java, I encode using this code(I'm not sure is relevant):

```
BitMatrix bitMatrix = barcodeWriter.encode(link_results, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 400, 400);    
BufferedImage bi = MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(bitMatrix);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", baos);
```

Comment: You may want to use serial port mode instead of keyboard input emulation mode.

Comment: This is not a choice for me, the scanner is not in my possession, I only generate the QR codes. I can't set the serial port in the QR code this must be a setting on the scanner, right?

Comment: That's right. It will be supported by the scanner and the system. And under such conditions, it is better to give up. There is nothing you can do with just a barcode. No matter what measures you take, you need to take action on the system side.